# can we create more than one indexes in ES using NEST at a time

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a requirement where I need to create new indexes using NEST in ES on the fly based on the user inputs.  Here I can create one index but how do I create multiple indexes at a time with single call ?.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(indexURL));        
                settings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
                settings.RequestTimeout();
                settings.PingTimeout();
                settings.MaximumRetries();
   var _client = new Nest.ElasticClient(settings);`
```

Comment: Where are you creating the index? You're creating an instance of the client, but need to call `_client.CreateIndex("index-name");` to create an index.

Comment: you are correct!.I missed to add that line of code here.  However, how do we create multiple indexes using createIndex with single call ?.. thank you for your quick response. Ingore this line of code : settings.DefaultIndex(indexName);

Answer (score 0):

You can only create one index per `CreateIndex()` call. There are strategies that you can take however if you will be creating multiple indices with the same mapping, or need to apply conventions to how properties will be mapped.

By default, if you try to index a document into a non-existent index, the index will be created and the mapping for the type will be inferred by Elasticsearch from the first document it sees. This may be useful for your use case, and you can take it further by controlling the mapping of auto created indices using

### [Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

You can define an index template to apply a mapping to a newly created index that matches the template field. Using `*` will match any index

```
var putIndexTemplateResponse = client.PutIndexTemplate("default", t => t
    .Template("*")
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map("_default_", tm => tm
            .Properties(p => p
                .Keyword(k => k
                    .Name("id")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This will map the `id` property for any type in any newly created index as a `keyword` field.

### [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)

If you need something more type/property convention based, you can use dynamic templates with rules to determine how dynamically added fields should be mapped

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("index-name", t => t
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map("_default_", tm => tm
            .DynamicTemplates(d => d
                .DynamicTemplate("default", dt => dt
                    .Match("id")
                    .MatchMappingType("string")
                    .Mapping(mm => mm
                        .Keyword(k => k)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Both approaches set mapping conventions within Elasticsearch.